# Unable to sync testnet node

Tags: stellar-core, testnet

I am using stellar-core in ubuntu 18.04 . I want to create test-network . But my node is unable to sync , it is stuck showing the log

```
    For new syntax: stellar-core help

2019-06-07T11:38:26.889 GDRLE [default INFO] Starting stellar-core stellar-core 11.1.0 (324c1bd61b0e9bada63e0d696d799421b00a7950)
2019-06-07T11:38:26.902 GDRLE [Database INFO] Connecting to: postgresql://dbname=testnet host=localhost user=minhajs password=********
2019-06-07T11:38:26.922 GDRLE [SCP INFO] LocalNode::LocalNode@GDRLE qSet: 273af2
2019-06-07T11:38:26.922 GDRLE [default INFO] Listening on 127.0.0.1:11626 for HTTP requests
2019-06-07T11:38:26.930 GDRLE [Database INFO] DB schema is in current version
2019-06-07T11:38:26.931 GDRLE [History INFO] Archive 'h1' has 'get' command only, will not be written
2019-06-07T11:38:26.931 GDRLE [History INFO] Archive 'h2' has 'get' command only, will not be written
2019-06-07T11:38:26.931 GDRLE [History INFO] Archive 'h3' has 'get' command only, will not be written
2019-06-07T11:38:26.932 GDRLE [History WARNING] No writable archives configured, history will not be written.
2019-06-07T11:38:26.932 GDRLE [Ledger INFO] Starting up application
2019-06-07T11:38:26.934 GDRLE [default INFO] Connection effective settings:
2019-06-07T11:38:26.934 GDRLE [default INFO] TARGET_PEER_CONNECTIONS: 8
2019-06-07T11:38:26.934 GDRLE [default INFO] MAX_ADDITIONAL_PEER_CONNECTIONS: 64
2019-06-07T11:38:26.934 GDRLE [default INFO] MAX_PENDING_CONNECTIONS: 500
2019-06-07T11:38:26.934 GDRLE [default INFO] MAX_OUTBOUND_PENDING_CONNECTIONS: 16
2019-06-07T11:38:26.934 GDRLE [default INFO] MAX_INBOUND_PENDING_CONNECTIONS: 484
2019-06-07T11:38:26.934 GDRLE [default INFO] Loading last known ledger
2019-06-07T11:38:26.940 GDRLE [Ledger INFO] Loaded last known ledger: [seq=1, hash=9c0fc9]
2019-06-07T11:38:26.941 GDRLE [Overlay INFO] Binding to endpoint 0.0.0.0:11625
2019-06-07T11:38:26.943 GDRLE [default INFO] * 
2019-06-07T11:38:26.943 GDRLE [default INFO] * Force-starting scp from the current db state. (`force scp` flag cleared in the db)
2019-06-07T11:38:26.943 GDRLE [default INFO] * 
2019-06-07T11:38:26.943 GDRLE [Herder INFO] Force joining SCP with local state
2019-06-07T11:38:26.943 GDRLE [Ledger INFO] Changing state LM_BOOTING_STATE -> LM_SYNCED_STATE
2019-06-07T11:39:01.941 GDRLE [Herder WARNING] Lost track of consensus
2019-06-07T11:39:01.942 GDRLE [Herder WARNING] Out of sync context: {
   "queue" : null,
   "scp" : {
      "2" : {
         "ballotProtocol" : {
            "ballot" : "(<null_ballot>)",
            "heard" : false,
            "phase" : "PREPARE",
            "state" : "i: 2 | PREPARE | b: (<null_ballot>) | p: (<null_ballot>) | p': (<null_ballot>) | h: (<null_ballot>) | c: (<null_ballot>) | M: 0"
         },
         "nomination" : {
            "X" : [ "[ txH: 392ada, ct: 1559887706, upgrades: [ ] ]" ],
            "roundnumber" : 8,
            "started" : true
         },
         "quorum_sets" : {
            "273af2" : {
               "t" : 2,
               "v" : [ "sdf1", "sdf2", "sdf3" ]
            }
         },
         "statements" : [
            [
               1559887709,
               "{ENV@GDRLE |  i: 2 | NOMINATE | D: 273af2 | X: {'[ txH: 392ada, ct: 1559887706, upgrades: [ ] ]'} | Y: {} }",
               true
            ]
         ],
         "validated" : true
      }
   },
   "you" : "GDRLEVIYCSPF4Z5ZPPNURZGF7GTBDCBVSDLCD3Y5C6KJTVHO43HWHOF6"
}
```

. 
My configuration file is

```
HTTP_PORT=11626
PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT=false
PEER_PORT=11625

NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="Test network"
RUN_STANDALONE=false
KNOWN_PEERS=[
"core-testnet1.stellar.org",
"core-testnet2.stellar.org",
"core-testnet3.stellar.org"]



DATABASE="postgresql://dbname=testnet host=localhost user=minhajs password=minhajs"
NODE_SEED="SBTBCMET7YMAMYXF2KSV63CSRLDMD5AO3FDELN4HCPY6UR2KBZBASRF6"
#Public: GDRLEVIYCSPF4Z5ZPPNURZGF7GTBDCBVSDLCD3Y5C6KJTVHO43HWHOF6

NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true

UNSAFE_QUORUM=true
FAILURE_SAFETY=1

#The public keys of the Stellar testnet servers
[QUORUM_SET]
THRESHOLD_PERCENT=51 # rounded up -> 2 nodes out of 3
VALIDATORS=[
"GDKXE2OZMJIPOSLNA6N6F2BVCI3O777I2OOC4BV7VOYUEHYX7RTRYA7Y  sdf1",
"GCUCJTIYXSOXKBSNFGNFWW5MUQ54HKRPGJUTQFJ5RQXZXNOLNXYDHRAP  sdf2",
"GC2V2EFSXN6SQTWVYA5EPJPBWWIMSD2XQNKUOHGEKB535AQE2I6IXV2Z  sdf3"]


#The history store of the Stellar testnet
[HISTORY.h1]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_001/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.h2]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_002/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.h3]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/core_testnet_003/{0} -o {1}"
```

Can someone help if encountered the same error . 
I used this same configuration on MacOs and it just worked fine .

Answer (score 1):

It's pointless to use the `KNOWN_PEERS` and `[HISTORY]` configuration for the official common testnet, as no other node will track or serve data from your *private* network.

If you want to join the SDF official testnet

- NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="Test SDF Network ; September 2015"

If you want to run your own network and it's your first node:

- Set it to [standalone mode](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/docs/stellar-core_standalone.cfg)
- Create your own history archive (see example in standalone config, needs to be initialized with `stellar-core new-hist` command first)
- Kickstart your network with the `stellar-core force-scp` command

If your own network is running and you want to add another node:

- Make sure your history from above is accessable for your new node
- Refer to the `[HISTORY]` that your first node writes, only the get command
- Refer to your first (and all other existing) nodes as `KNOWN_PEERS`

Comment: I changed the NETWORK_PASSPHRASE and then tried , It is able to connect to nodes but the situation persists , that it has lost track of consensus . And new nodes are connected and dropped due to limited slots .

Comment: You have to completely start over when changing passphrase. Clear all data with `stellar-core new-db`